# Using one funnction instead of many functions

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of images that are individually updating a drop down selection box. I've been using the following: (changing the replaceContent(number) and a different selectIndex = (number) inside a separate function for each image).

```
function replaceContent9() {
     document.getElementById("ecwid-productoption-8840317-Backgrounds")
             .selectedIndex = 0 ; }
```

I call the function like this:

```
javascript:replaceContent9
```

How would I do this with an array so that I might have just one function that is used for all the images. So far not so good at figuring out arrays. Maybe someone could point me in the right direction or suggest a code to try.

Comment: Can you add some more relevant code. Like your HTML and the part where you call the functions

Comment: read : [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) or [for..each](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a hash/lookup object:

```
var replaceContent = (function() {
    var info = {
        0:   'ecwid-productoption-8840317-Backgrounds',
        1:   'foobar-product',
        9:   'whhooott rage'
    };

    return function( which ) {
        document.getElementById( info[ which ] ).selectedIndex = 0 ;
    };
}());
```

This object in its current form pretty much looks like a javascript array because of indexed key names, but for a more general use you should do it like this.

Now you can just call that function like

```
replaceContent( 9 );
```

Comment: Thanks this works but maybe I should have been a little more detailed in my question. Using the function to update the drop-down box selection option i would need to change the selectedIndex = (n) for each individual image click

Comment: Here's the page. Just select the backgrounds button. The above code is on the first image button and the other buttons have the original function listed in my post. 
http://www.frysa.us/jackets.htm#ecwid:category=1206017&mode=product&product=8840317

Comment: I've been using a WYSIWYG editor (XARA) so the HTML is very cryptic. That's the problem with those types of editors. I have been able to insert my own code into a placeholder for the page etc... and that's where the above functions have been placed. Thanks

Comment: I managed to adapt your code to my needs. It works great! Thanks a lot